# Solve command returns duplicate answers

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

Mathematica 11.0.1.

In the documentation for the Solve command:

When a single variable is specified and a particular root of an equation has multiplicity greater than one, Solve gives several copies of the corresponding solution.

So this is understandable:

```
In[8]:= Solve[(x - 2)^2 (x - 1) == 0, x]

Out[8]= {{x -> 1}, {x -> 2}, {x -> 2}}
```

But this makes me curious.

```
In[10]:= Solve[Cos[2 t - π/2] == -1 && 0 <= t <= 2 Pi, t]

Out[10]= {{t -> (3 π)/4}, {t -> (3 π)/4}, {t -> (7 π)/
   4}, {t -> (7 π)/4}}
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. Any thoughts?

Comment: As the first derivative of the function is zero at the root, it is effectively a double root.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the exact reason, but you can avoid it by using `NSolve`

```
NSolve[TrigToExp@Cos[2 t - Pi / 2] == -1 && 0 <= t <= 2 Pi, t]
```

> {{t -> 2.35619}, {t -> 5.49779}}

With `Solve` if you use `0 <= t <= 2.0 Pi` you will get the same result with an error message about inexact coefficient.

So my guess is when you use `Solve` with exact numbers, it probably convert the trigonometric function into a polynomial, where it sees a double root - just a guess, though.

Comment: you could do `Union@Solve` as well

Answer (score 3):

We can predict the multiplicity of the root based on the number of zero derivatives at the root.
For example

```
Solve[x^10 == 0, x] // Length
(* 10 *)
```

Consider

```
expr = -126 + 210 Cos[x] - 120 Cos[2 x] + 45 Cos[3 x] - 10 Cos[4 x] + 
   Cos[5 x];
Series[expr, {x, 0, 10}] // Normal
(* -(x^10/2) *)
```

which has is zero up to 10th order.  This has a 10 fold root

```
sols = Solve[expr == 0 && Abs[x] < 1/5, x];
Union[sols]
Length[sols]
(* {{x -> 0}} *)
(* 10 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Reduce` avoids duplicated answers

To use @mikados example:

```
Plot[x^10, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

```
sol = Reduce[x^10 == 0, x]
```

> x == 0

To get a `Solve`-like output:

```
List@ToRules@sol
```

> {{x -> 0}}